# boolean recursion part 2

Tags: java, recursion

trying to write a boolean function that returns true if 'm' is a ancestor of the current class. 'm' is an ancestor if it is a mom or dad, or a ancestor of mom or dad.

will this get me there?

```
public boolean isAncestor(member m){
        if (mom == m || dad == m){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            if(isAncestor(m.mom) || isAncestor(m.dad)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: How are you using the `==` operator to compare `mom == m` and `dad == m`?

Comment: stop condition...right.doh! thanks!

Comment: Now that I think about it, how does your method know which two individuals it is comparing?

Comment: My answer below is actually comparing two members now as opposed to just mom or dad status for a given member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, more or less. What if you get to a layer of the ancestry where mom or dad aren't known, and are null?

```
public boolean isAncestor(member m){
        if (m == null)
            return false;
        if (mom.equals(m) || dad.equals(m))
            return true;
        else if(isAncestor(m.mom) || isAncestor(m.dad))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is just getting if someone is a parent or not, you actually need to send two members as parameters if you want to compare their relationship. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The logic will get you there, however one must take care with the equal signs.

In Java `==` compares for equality of instances.  Odds are good that over time you will have two instances which are comparatively equal but exist in different instances.  If your code has been written to prevent such a thing from occurring, then you don't need to change the `==` to `.equals(...)`; but, if you didn't put in any safeguards to ensure only one instance of each "same" object exists, then you might want to change the comparison to `.equals(...)` and implement an custom "public boolean equals(Object other) {...}` method for the base "person" class.

Comment: This depends a bit from what we want the method to do in such a case. If there are two copies of my family, am I still a child of the mom in the other copy?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use recurrsion, you are going to need to have a stop condition. Does everyone have a mom or a dad? consider this:

```
public boolean isAncestor(Member m) {
     // stop condition
    if(this.mom == null && this.dad == null) return false;
    // stop condition
    if(this.mom == m || this.dad == m) return true;
    // loop condition
    return mom.isAncestor(m) || dad.isAncestor(m);
}
```

Comment: what if only one parent is known?

Comment: As an aside, @Edwin is very correct about using `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: @6NSString good point, there needs to be a condition to check m for being null as well. For that matter, this might be going the "wrong direction" on the tree from what OP wants. I haven't put much thought into it. The point was to illustrate the idea of checking to make sure they actually HAVE parents.

Answer (score 0):

It might but it is not 100% correct. You should also check if mum and dad exist otherwise you might end up with NullPointerException.

Moreover the others are correct with the `==` usage, quite suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

When does the recursion stop, if there is no relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need a way to know which two members you are comparing for relationship. You'll probably want to do something like this (untested):

```
/**
 * @param m1 the member we want to get ancestry from
 * @param m2 the member we presume is an ancestor
 */
public boolean isAncestor(member m1, member m2){
    if (m1 == NULL || m2 == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    if (m1.isMom(m2) || m1.isDad(m2)){
        return true;
    }
    else if(isAncestor(m1.mom, m2) || isAncestor(m1.dad, m2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'd need to write `isMom` and `isDad` to compare the relationship of `m2` to `m1`.

Comment: If we make this object-oriented, `isAnchestor` would be a method of the member class, so your first parameter is not necessary.